# c++ Polymorphism : segfault and reference strange behaviour with arrays

Tags: arrays, c++11, reference, segmentation-fault, polymorphism

Here is a [MWE](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMinimal_Working_Example&ei=8FkVVaGvLsvwUvnkgGA&usg=AFQjCNHlT9foe55eGSIYE_kIlKfcpqWZRQ&bvm=bv.89381419,d.d24) that, when compiled with `g++ -std=c++11`, produces a
segmentation fault:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class Rand{
    public:
        Rand(double const& min_inclusive, double const& max_exclusive):
            mt_(std::random_device()()),
            dist_(min_inclusive,max_exclusive){}
        ~Rand(){}
        double get() { return dist_(mt_); }
    private:
        std::mt19937_64 mt_;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist_;
};

class Base {
    public:
        Base():rnd(0.0,1.0){ std::cout<<"Base created "<<&rnd<<" "<<rnd.get()<<std::endl; }
        virtual ~Base(){};
        Rand rnd;
};

class Child: public Base{
    public:
        Child():var(1.0){ std::cout<<"Child created"<<std::endl; }
        double var;
};

class Other {
    public:
        Other(Base* b):b(b){  std::cout<<"Other created "<<&(b[0].rnd)<<" and "<<&(b[1].rnd)<<"--->"<<b[0].rnd.get()<<" "<<b[1].rnd.get()<<std::endl; }
        Base* b;
};

int main(){
    unsigned int N(2);
    std::cout<<"#############"<<std::endl;
    Base* b(new Base[N]);
    Other o1(b);
    std::cout<<"#############"<<std::endl;
    Child* c(new Child[N]);
    Other o2(c);
    std::cout<<"#############"<<std::endl;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
}
```

The typical output is :

```
#############
Base created 0x239c020 0.226514
Base created 0x239ca00 0.902337
Other created 0x239c020 and 0x239ca00--->0.864321 0.302185
#############
Base created 0x239d3f0 0.573563
Child created
Base created 0x239ddd8 0.422187
Child created
Other created 0x239d3f0 and 0x239ddd0--->0.909183 4.94066e-324
#############
```

In the first part where a `Base` class is given to `Other` the references are
coherent and the code runs properly.

But when a `Child` class is given to `Other`, the first reference is identical
but the second is slightly different. The direct consequence of that is that
the `b[1].rdn.get()` is always (very close) '0'. The other indirect consequence
is that the code ends with a SegFault...

Moreover, when `Child::var` is absent, the program works fine, all references
are coherent and there is no SegFault.

What am I doing wrong ? Is it impossible to create `Other` with a child of
`Base` ? If so, it looks like the polymorphism is ruined...

## EDIT

According to a nice answer :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Rand{
    public:
        Rand(double const& min_inclusive, double const& max_exclusive):
            mt_(std::random_device()()),
            dist_(min_inclusive,max_exclusive){}
        ~Rand(){}
        double get() { return dist_(mt_); }
    private:
        std::mt19937_64 mt_;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist_;
};

class Base {
    public:
        Base():rnd(0.0,1.0){ std::cout<<"Base created "<<&rnd<<" "<<rnd.get()<<std::endl; }
        virtual ~Base(){};
        Rand rnd;
};

class Child: public Base{
    public:
        Child():var(0.0){ std::cout<<"Child created"<<std::endl; }
        double var;
};

template<typename Type>
class Other {
    public:
        Other(unsigned int N):b_(N){
            std::cout<<"Other created "<<std::endl;
            for(unsigned int i(0);i<b_.size();i++){
                b_[i] = std::make_shared<Type>();
            }
        }
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> > b_;
};

int main(){
    unsigned int N(2);
    std::cout<<"#############"<<std::endl;
    Other<Base> o1(N);
    std::cout<<"#############"<<std::endl;
    Other<Child> o2(N);
    std::cout<<"#############"<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array of `Child` you can't treat it as an array of `Base`. This means that when for example you call `b[1].rnd.get()`, you invoke undefined behavior.

Why is that? When you have a `Child* c` and you convert it to `Base*`, the result of conversion is a pointer to a `Base` subobject of `Child`. So `(Base*)c + 1` will point to the next byte after that subobject, which in your case is the first byte of `var`.

When `Child` doesn't have data members, `(Base*)c + 1` points to the next object, so everything works.

In order to achieve polymorphic behavior you should create an array of *pointers* to `Base`:

```
Base** b{new Base*[N]};
```

Initialize each array element with whatever descendant of `Base` and enjoy polymorphism.

Edit: as it was reasonably pointed out by [vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093378/vsoftco) in the comments, it's better not to use raw pointers and arrays:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> b {...}
```

Comment: better to get rid of C-like arrays altogether and use `std::vector<Base*>`, or better, `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`

Comment: @AntonSavin,@vsoftco I have updated my question according to your help ! but i still have some problems...

Comment: @PinkFloyd you have to initialize vector elements (with `new` or better `make_shared`). Right now you are passing a vector of `N` null pointers.

Comment: @PinkFloyd and even worse, the whole line `Other o1(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> >(N));` is treated as function declaration due to [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: then I'm lost :-( I tried with `Other o1(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> >(N,std::make_shared<Base>()));`  and `Other o2(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Child> >(N,std::make_shared<Child>()));` but it doesn't compile

Comment: @PinkFloyd this discussion went far away from the original question. Your code even if compiles (which can be done) doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: ok, I understand. Nevertheless, before I accept your answer, could you tell my what you think of my last solution ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd [it looks like it's working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/476916490258b88e) but the vectors you create consist of N pointers to the same object.